# Sorting the bits of a 32-bit vector. Verilog

Tags: sorting, verilog, digital-logic

I need to do a design that sorts the bits of a 32-bit vector(not sure if it's called vector) like this:

`1010010101010 => 00000001111111`

I must have a 32-bit parallel in and a serial out and it must be combinational.

I tried something like this:

```
assign c=in[0]+in[1]+in[2]+in[3]+in[4]+in[5]+in[6]+in[7]+in[8]+in[9]+in[10]+in[11]+in[12]+in[13]+in[14]+in[15]+in[16]+in[17]+in[18]+in[19]+in[20]+in[21]+in[22]+in[23]+in[24]+in[25]+in[26]+in[27]+in[28]+in[29]+in[30]+in[31];

assign out=(1<< c)-1;
```

But I thought I would need to do the design sequential if I count the ones.

Can you please help me do this? My head hurts from trying to understand verilog.

Comment: Your posted solution is combinational - you're not using any registers. Your critical path will be long, but it should work.

Comment: I don't think you can have a serial output implemented with combinational circuit, you need a clock and register(s).

Answer (score 0):

"Serial out" means 1 bit per cycle. You need a 1-bit `out` signal and a counter  that selects one of the 32-bits of the result. Assuming your clock is called `clk` and your active-low reset `rstn`

```
logic[31:0] result;
logic[4:0] cnt;
assign c=in[0]+in[1]+in[2]+in[3]+in[4]+in[5]+in[6]+in[7]+in[8]+in[9]+in[10]+in[11]+in[12]+in[13]+in[14]+in[15]+in[16]+in[17]+in[18]+in[19]+in[20]+in[21]+in[22]+in[23]+in[24]+in[25]+in[26]+in[27]+in[28]+in[29]+in[30]+in[31];
assign result = (1 << c) - 1;
always_ff @(posedge clk, negedge rstn)
   if (!rstn)
       cnt <= 0;
   else
       cnt <= cnt+1;
assign out = result[cnt];
```